# mysql query reverse printing

Tags: mysql

Please HELP -- query is printing old news first. I need to reverse the order.

```
$query = "SELECT post_title, `post_content`, `post_name` FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date > '$start' AND post_date < '$end' AND post_type='news' AND post_status = 'publish'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $news = '';

    if (mysql_numrows($result) <= 0) {
        echo "No results for - NEWS<br/><br/>";
    } else {
        while ($cnews = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {


            $post_title = $cnews['post_title'];
            $text = formatText_mt(($cnews['post_content']));

            $news = '<a href=“#’.$cnews['post_name'].'">' . ($post_title) . '</a><br><br>';
            echo $news;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use MySql `ORDER BY` to order your results.

```
"SELECT post_title, `post_content`, `post_name` FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date > '$start' 
AND post_date < '$end' AND post_type='news' 
AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date ASC"
```

You can `<sql> ORDER BY <column>` `ASC`ending or `DESC`ending.

[Read the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html).

Also really, ***STOP*** using `MySQL_` functions. You should be using `MySQLi_` or `PDO` PHP/Database intefaces. `mysql_` is DEPRECATED meaning it is insecure and no longer maintained or supported.

And `mysql_numrows` ==> You mean `mysql_num_rows`

You are also vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) and should be using Parameterised queries using **Prepared Statements**. [Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`ORDER BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) with `DESC` on a column which denotes date-time.